# Divisibility on product of two numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $p$ be a prime, and $a$ and $b$ two integers, such that $p\not|$ $a$ and $p\not|$ $b$.

It can be possible that $p$ $|$ $ab$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Have you tried some examples? Notice any patterns?

Comment: I think it is false :D!

Comment: Great! Do you have an example that makes you think this?

Comment: @JohnHughes: An example is not quite going to suffice in this case...

Comment: @penguina: Let $[a_1,\dots,a_m]$ be the prime factors of $a$ and $[b_1,\dots,b_n]$ be the prime factors of $b$. What can you say about the prime factors of $ab$?

Comment: It will be $[a_1,..,a_m,b_1,..,b_n]$, and I see it now. It will be false, p will not be any of these factors. Thank you!

Comment: @penguina: Keep in mind that some of these factors may be common to both $a$ and $b$, so the correct way of phrasing it would be using *set* notation (e.g., let $A=\{x\mid x\text{ is a prime factor of }a\}$ and $B=\{y\mid y\text{ is a prime factor of }b\}$, then $A\cup B$ is the set of prime factors of $ab$)...

Comment: Yes, you are right! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Recall that a prime $p$ divides an integer $a$ iff $p$ is in the [integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) (which is unique) of $a$. If you know the integer factorizations of $a$ and $b$, what is the integer factorization of their product?
What may we conclude?

Comment: Thank you! It is clear now. The answer is false!

Comment: @penguina Well done!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The contrapositive of

$(p|ab) \Rightarrow (p|a$ or $p|b)$

answers your question.

Comment: Right... It's like proving $x \implies y$ by assuming $\neg y \implies \neg x$... But the latter is not given in the question, so you still need to prove it. With your method, we could just as well prove that every integer is a multiple of $5$, by assuming that if a number is not a multiple of $5$ then it is not an integer.

Comment: It's just the definition of prime element. Given a ring $R$ and an element $x\in R$, we say that $x$ is an prime element iff $x|ab \Rightarrow x|a$ or $x|b$ for $a,b\in R$.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. If $p\not|a$ and $p\not|b$ then $p$ is not in prime factorisation of $a$ and $b$. Hence, $p$ is not in prime factorisation of $ab$

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{N}$ we have a unique factorization, it means $a=p_1^{n_1}...p_k^{n_k}$. So if $p$ doesn't appear in factorization of a or b, it means it doesn't appear in $ab$.

Comment: Side note: for the specific question at hand, the multiplicity of each prime factor (i.e., $n_1,\dots,n_k$) is not important.